# What's the command to type a phrase?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, mouse

I'm trying to bind a certain key combination that types my E-Mail. I want it so that when I press a certain key combination, it types a certain phrase (my E-Mail).

Basically- I need a command that types a certain phrase when ran.

Comment: What application will you be typing your email address into?

Comment: Hi Josh, *if* the answer solved your problem, would you be so kind to consider accepting the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. The command to type a phrase

You can do that by using `xdotool`, which is not on your system by default. Install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Then the command to (literally) type a text phrase is:

```
xdotool type 'This is a test to see if all works fine. If it works this text is typed.'
```

The text will be typed in the frontmost window.

#### Adding it to a shortcut key

Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command (e.g.):

```
xdotool type 'This is a test to see if all works fine. If it works this text is typed.'
```

### 2. Alternatively

More complicated is to use both `xdotool` *and* `xclip`, which both need to be installed:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool xclip
```

Then the command to *paste* a text into the front most window would be:

```
printf 'This is a test to see if all works fine. If it works this text is typed.' | xclip -sel clip && xdotool key Control_L+v
```

#### Notes on the second option

- Mind that this (second) option works if the front most application uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste text, which is *not* the case with e.g. `gnome-terminal`, which uses <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
  Therefore, the command to paste text into a terminalwindow would be:

  ```
  printf 'This is a test to see if all works fine. If it works this text is typed.' | xclip -sel clip && xdotool key Shift_L+Control_L+v
  ```
- If you would like to include a newline after your phrase is pasted, replace `printf` by `echo`

Comment: Also, do you know a command that "presses" the backspace? I couldn't find *anything* about it on Google.

Comment: @JoshHonig I am not at home right now, but you can find out by typing `xev` in a terminal and press return, then type the key you want to type. I will edit it into my answer tomorrow.

Comment: I found it. Thank you for the answer! Worked like a charm